# How to debug client certificate using IIS5.1 on XP and C#

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate, self-signed

Ola,

I need to develop a website (in C#, asp.net 3.5) that will require client certificates. I'd like to debug this, using Visual Studio. I have setup IIS to use a self-signed certificate using the excellent tool [SelfSSL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671) I have also setup the default site to require SSL and to require client certificates. But I do not know how to create a client certificate that is accepted by IIS. When browsing to the testsite I get the (expected) error:

```
HTTP 403.7 - Forbidden: Client certificate required
```

How can I create a client certificate?

[UPDATE] I have created a certificate with makecert, as suggested by sipwiz. However, IIS doesn't seem to recognize this certificate as a valid client certificate. I've exported the servers certificate and added the -ic (servercert) switch. This still doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft's makecert utility.

You may need to tweak the command line options but something like the below should get you started:

makecert -pe -n "CN=MyName" -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -ss my clientcer.cer

Edit: Added -eku parameter, looks like it's needed for IIS client certs.

Comment: Thanks. I've created a cert, and imported in IE, but it is not 'recognized' as a client certificate for localhost. Trying other commandline options now.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your "client certificates" loaded into your personal certificate store?

Run > mmc > Add/Remove Snap-in > Certificates > My user account > Personal > Certificates

That is where IE expects the client certificates to be. Once there, IE will ask you which certificate to use.

Brandon